# Task Scheduler Windows 7 - Missed task is started only sometimes

Tags: windows-7, taskscheduler

I am trying to schedule a GUI program with the Task Scheduler on Windows 7 Home Basic. The run frequency is Daily and I have checked the option "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed". But the task only runs sometimes (after a delay of 10 minutes) when a scheduled start is missed. It usually stays in the Ready status and does not start. In the task history, there is no event for a missed task. (Occasionally, the task does get triggered 10 minutes after startup.)

What is the reason for this erratic behavior ?

Comment: This seems more like a Windows problem than a programming one.

Comment: Please ask it in [superuser.se]

Comment: Have asked on superuser. Thanks.